# Oracle 19c Database generate JSON from rows without passing field names

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle19c

I am trying to find a way to query relational tables, without prior knowledge about the table, to generate each row returned as a JSON object without having to execute two queries to achieve this outcome.

For example, If I have a '**Table_1**' with columns a,b and c. I am seeking a way to write a single query that will return me json representing each row.

```
{
  "a":"value of a",
  "b":"value of b",
  "c":"value of c"
}
```

At this time, I have to execute the following query to find the column names:

```
SELECT INTO LISTAGG(column_name,', ') from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME="Table_1"
```

I then formulate a second query (on the client) based on the results of the previous query that gives me the **COLUMN_NAMES**

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(colnames) from Table_1;
```

I am trying to save 2 trips to the database by combining the two queries but to no avail. Any idea on how to make this work? I have tried so many permutations and combinations.

Tried this: won't work.

```
begin
SELECT INTO colnames LISTAGG(column_name,', ') from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='Table_1' and owner ='owner1'
select JSON_OBJECT(colnames) from Table_1 where a LIKE '%';
END;
```

Another failed attempt:

```
select JSON_OBJECT(SELECT LISTAGG(column_name,', ') from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='Table_1' and owner ='owner1') from Table_1 where a LIKE '%'
```

Comment: Have you tried select JSON_OBJECT(*) from table_1 where a like '%'; .... This assumes you want ALL the columns but seems to work on a very simple example I tried.

Comment: Yes! that works! I just need to figure out how to accept this answer...! Thanks again!